# Postgis : separate nested polygons

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection, union

I'm working on OpenStreetMap data on Postgis. I have in a table "roads_polygons_label" containing all the polygons and roads in a given area and for each of them a label saying what it is (e.g. building, residential, grassland, according to OSM database). The problem is that some polygons are nested. For instance polygon A labeled as "residential" contains polygons B and C both labeled as "building". I want to separate A from B and C  to get three records:

- polygon A\(BuC) labeled as "residential"
- polygon B labeled as "building"
- polygon C labeled as "building"

I managed to get a table "overlapping" where I join "roads_polygons_label" with itself on an ST_Intersects query to have for each larger polygon a row for each polygon it contains. So in my basic example it would give two records for polygon A:

- A - B
- A - C

Then I wanted to use ST_Union to make a big multipolygon made of all polygons nested in one larger polygon, so here a polygon made of BuC. But I would need to loop on each larger polygon and I don't know how to do that. I can create a table "large_polys" listing all polygons containing smaller polygons, but then I don't know how to join "overlapping" with "large-polys" in the loop.
I have read the following posts but they did not provide a solution for me problem:

[Separate polygons based on intersection using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83/separate-polygons-based-on-intersection-using-postgis)

[SQL Server - Select all polygons nested within a larger polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182246/sql-server-select-all-polygons-nested-within-a-larger-polygon)

Edit : illustration of what I mean:
[image: nested polygons]
Maybe "nested" is not the right term.
A, B and C have different osm ids. I also have several polygons with the same id and different area, but that's another issue.

Comment: Something that isn't clear to me is what you mean by 'nested' polygons. The example you give sounds like A, B, and C are currently a multipolygon, but somehow each polygon part has different attributes. This isn't something I've encountered in PostGIS before and I'm having trouble finding any documentation on how that would work.

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean by "some polygons are nested. For instance polygon A labeled as "residential" contains polygons B and C both labeled as "building". I want to separate A from B and C to get three records", show us a picture or provide some geojson so for this example so we can play with it

Comment: See my edit, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I think I, solved it with a simple groupby on my larger polygons to use ST_Union on the contained polygons, and then ST_Difference on the larger polygon and the union.